# How many spears can I expect from an average asparagus plant ready for harvest?

Tags: harvesting, asparagus

Pictures of young asparagus plants seem to indicate multiple spears will come from a single plant.  But pictures of mature plants are harder to interpret.

I want to know so that I can determine how many asparagus plants I should plant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=how%20many%20spears%20of%20asparagus%20grow%20on%20one%20plant&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http://ohioline.osu.edu/hyg-fact/1000/1603.html&ei=iap5T9yrFqHE0QH8_JjcDQ&usg=AFQjCNHvt0TA8oU0u3NNRhXVdrT6V6_cbw), a mature asparagus crown will produce a half pound a year, which is about twenty spears a year per plant. A good rule of thumb is to plant ten plants for each family member.